# Celery tasks.py only does one of many subprocesses in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, subprocess, celery

My Django app's goal is to serve as a GUI for two Python programs. So besides the landing page, I have a form wherein after submitting, the tasks.py will be called.

What my tasks.py does (overview):

1. The choices or options in the form will be replaced by arguments passed to the 1st program via if-else conditions.
2. Then these args will be passed to the first program.
3. After that, it will pass to the 2nd program.
4. This program needs the Virtualbox to be opened because it is a sandbox app. Also, it contains two subprocess.popen() because it will run the sandbox app then the submit script.
5. I will also be adding args with the input depending on its type before analysis. Since the sandbox app, doesn't terminate by itself and just stops after Ctrl+C, I use subprocess.kill() after reading its stdout and stderr if it contains strings saying it is successfully processed.
6. In the end, I'll send a subprocess to turn off the Virtualbox.

So far, here is an idea about my code:

```
@shared_task(name='tasks.process_sample_input')
def process_sample_input(instance_id):
try:
    vm_open = subprocess.Popen(["VBoxManage", "startvm", "WindowsXP", "--type", "headless"])
    args = list()
    args = fill_args(instance_id) #this contains the if conditions for the additional arguments
    #some codes here for the thug_logs as log files
    first_process = subprocess.call((args), stdout=thug_logs, stderr = thug_logs)
    if first_process == 0:
       second_program(instance_id) 
       #this contains the subprocess.Popen for the 2nd program, also contains the subprocess.kill() for its subprocesses
    if vm_open is None: #If vm_open is still running
        subprocess.call(["vboxmanage", "controlvm", "CSG_Win", "poweroff"]) #turn it off
        vm_open.kill() #kill the popen command
except:
    logger.error("Problem in Celery tasks")
return None
```

My problem and questions:

1. My tasks just run the opening of the Virtualbox, it does not process the input in the first program. No changes in the first program's database so input wasn't received. (Main problem, just really not going to the 2nd subprocess)
2. I just chose the parts where to use subprocess.call and subprocess.popen. For those parts that may not close automatically, I sent kill() signals to terminate them.
3. Is it ok that I just put and call all these methods in just one tasks method or should the subprocess commands be in different tasks methods? That is the only task in my tasks.py and the others there are all Python methods.

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: is your first program : `first_process = subprocess.call((args), stdout=thug_logs, stderr = thug_logs)` ?

Comment: Yes, I call the first program (not mine) via subprocess.call since it terminates after processing the input. I'll add some details on the second program too